# bash script for analyzin file on runtime

Tags: linux, bash

I want to do a bash script for analyzing a log file for errors. 
I was looking an efficient way for getting the information as soon as they are written.

Can you suggest me some solutions?

Let's say my script will always running and getting each new line that is written in the log file, particulars events will generate alert or e-mail (that's not a problem).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tail -f` to continuously get new lines and act on them via bash's `read` built-in.

```
tail -f logfile | while read line; do
      test "$line" = "nuclear meltdown" && echo "Run for your life!"
done
```

Comment: you mean something like: while read line; do do_some_with $line; done < tail -f logfile ? Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, I mean something like that. There is always another way in shell programming :-).

Comment: ok, i guess there is like a cache that is flushed at a certain point. Because if I use your script and try to write some lines in the file, I got your script working just after 5 or 6 line written in the log, this it's not a big problem, but I would like to understand how the mechanism in tail work.

Comment: man tail says that tail -f continuously re-opens the file and sees if there is new output.

Comment: @Kerby82 - Yes, the pipe is buffered.

Comment: @mouviciel is the buffer of the pipe configurable?